# Making series of jpegs into videos on a PC

Tags: windows, video, photos

I have sets of timelapse photos (jpegs), that I want to turn into a video.

I prefer freeware as this is just some fun-projects.

I need to do this on a windows-pc, so no Mac-soft please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows Live Movie Maker](http://download.live.com/moviemaker).

[image]

Comment: I remembered answering a very similar question to this before...

Comment: you did, didn't you? :)

Comment: @Molly: Oh yes... Ooooh yeesss, I remember now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.org) for this. As long as your images are numbered sequentially you can open them like a video and export them as avi.

> To reading a series of numbered images as a video stream, use File > Open video file... and select the first image. VirtualDub will automatically step the filename and find any sequentially numbered frames after the starting file. - [Working with image sequences](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=34)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JPGVideo](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/jpgvideo.html), free and it looks like it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[MonkeyJam](http://www.giantscreamingrobotmonkeys.com/monkeyjam/features.html) is what you're looking for.  This software was originally designed for pencil tests, but you can use it for stop motion animation/time lapse videos too.

Answer (score 0):

1. download and run [**Portable Movie Maker**](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk)
2. import images
3. drag and drop images into the story board
4. save movie ... done and dusted.

p.s.: the most recent versions of (Windows Live) Movie Maker for Vista and 7 don't have all the features and transitions you can find on earlier builds. this portable variant, based on Movie Maker 2.1, does have all the "bells 'n' whistles", it works with with Windows XP, Vista, and Windows 7 (without installation).